# Governing equations

Tags: traduction, anglais, usage, anglicismes

> Governing Equations of Continuum Mechanics.
>
> Équations gouvernantes de la mécanique des milieux continus.

L'emploi de **équations gouvernantes** se considéré-t-il un anglicisme ? Dans ce cas, comment exprimer la même idée d'une façon plus francisée ?

(En effet, Linguee donne plusieurs interprétations.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Les équations sont celles qui *sont en train de gouverner* =>

*gouvernant* est ici un **participe présent**. => Invariable.

Alors oui pour *les équations **gouvernant** la méca*

EDIT : Note que l'on utilise aussi souvent le verbe ***régir***, relativement à des équations fondatrices : *qui **régissent** / régissant.*

Comment: Ça s'appelle contourner la question :-) Il y a des cas où on aurait vraiment besoin d'un adjectif.

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez : Je ne comprends pas vraiment ton besoin. Pour qualifier un truc agissant en tant que ce qu'il agit ? Bhein... il y a le participe présent c'est même fait pour cela. Pour qualifier le truc en soi... Bhein... pour qualifier les équations qui régissent une discipline on en a déja un d'adjectif : *fondamentales*.